# Parse through XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I've been reading through many tutorials and examples, but I'm lost. I have an XML file with this type of data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
  <property>
    <name>Client Property A</name>
    <phone>Client Property A Phone Number</phone>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Client Property B</name>
    <phone>Client Property B Phone Number</phone>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Client Property C</name>
    <phone>Client Property C Phone Number</phone>
  </property>
</properties>
```

I'm trying to parse through this data in C# but having no luck at all. I have this:

```
XmlTextReader xmldata = new XmlTextReader("http://url.to/xml");
   XmlNodeList xmllist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("property");
   processList( xmllist );

public void processList(XmlNodeList xmllist)
    {
        // Loop through each property node and list the information
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmllist)
        {
            XmlElement nodeElement = (XmlElement)node;
            txtBox.AppendText(nodeElement.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText);
            txtBox.AppendText(nodeElement.GetElementsByTagName("phone")[0].InnerText);
        }
    }
```

But nothing gets output in to my text box. :(

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: In your posted code, what is `doc`? You don't appear to be using `xmldata` for anything.

Comment: sorry, `doc` is `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();`

Comment: So it's just an empty `XmlDocument`?

Comment: I see that now. like I said, I'm lost on this one....

Comment: Start with "[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)". It's much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m_strFilePath = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=12414&hl=it";
string xmlStr;
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
}
var doc= new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

    XmlNodeList xmllist = doc.SelectNodes("//property");
       processList( xmllist );


    public void processList(XmlNodeList xmllist)
        {
            // Loop through each property node and list the information
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmllist)
            {
                XmlElement nodeElement = (XmlElement)node;
                txtBox.AppendText(nodeElement.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText);
                txtBox.AppendText(nodeElement.SelectSingleNode("phone").InnerText);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to Xml to get properties from your xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://url.to/xml");

foreach(var p in xdoc.Root.Elements("property"))
{
   txtBox.AppendText((string)p.Element("name"));
   txtBox.AppendText((string)p.Element("phone"));
}
```

Comment: While I do like your approach, @Haroldis kept it in a way that I could use... It is greatly appreciated though!! :)

Comment: -1: I'm sure you'll fix it quickly, and I'll remove the downvote, but "The XmlReader should be in a using block".

Comment: That does not call Dispose on the outer XmlReader. Also, even if the code you posted always did dispose the passed XmlReader, that's an implementation detail, and should not be depended upon.

Comment: @JohnSaunders yep, agree. I thought inner reader will close parent stream also. Looks like it does not. Actually we can remove reader completely here. XDocument is smart enough to get data from uri :)